# Which State Management approach is more preferable to update the data in real time?

Tags: flutter, provider, riverpod, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-streambuilder

We are working on Parking Management Application for our university where we are receiving the vehicle information. And if the entered vehicle is not registered, security guard have an option to approve and reject the entry of non-registered vehicle. There is movement of 30 two-wheelers in 10 min during peak hours.

Which state management is more preferable in this scenario? Data will be updating in real time and app shouldn't get slow.

I was thinking to use Riverpod but i am not sure whether it will be good or i should use getx.

Comment: If its just a small project getx will do, But if its quite big riverpod will do and it's unidirectional pattern, But the question is which one is better? Well that part it's quite neutral it depends on you actually

Answer (score 1):

There are many state management packages for flutter.

Below-mentioned packages are the best five packages or the top five packages:

[Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod), [Redux](https://pub.dev/packages/redux), [BLoC / Rx](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc), [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get), etc.

By the way, these packages are not in any order.

If you have a small project, I mean a Parking Management Application that is not as big as an E-commerce, Social Media or Social Messaging project. So you require something which is non-bloated, clean & minimal.

I recommend or suggest you go with the [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package. That package helps you to build `MVP (minimum viable product)`. It has features like,
`state management`, `route management` & `dependency management`.

Apart from that, [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) is the `#1 package` (with ~12894 likes) on the official [pub dev website](https://pub.dev/).

It's easy to learn as well as easy to implement. So, I can say that the [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) is beginner-friendly.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz, Every coin has two sides. Every mountain has a valley. For every strength there is a weakness. Every up has a down.

Comment: Thank you @DharamBudh for your valuable insights and suggestions.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz can you please elaborate more on your point specifically?

Comment: If you had questions about the video, leave comments there.  If you have a question for me, ask me.  Or come hang out on the flutter discord.